# half screen activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I would like to create an activity that takes only half of the screen and in the other half its shows the background (whether it's the home screen or another application).

One more thing is that the user should be able to use the rest of the screen.

Does anybody know how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not do exactly what you want - meaning it is not a half screen for sure, but it does allow you to build apps that show in floating windows so users can interact with stuff behinf the app.  I have not used it but I thought it looked cool:

[StandOut link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1688531)

Comment: Thank you its exactly what i wanted

Comment: There is any framework like StandOut on iphone? or any other way to do it in iphone?

Comment: Don't believe so because iOS does not have true multitasking.

Comment: There is no way to create popup window that is always on top and take only part of the screen?